# PhpStorm doesn't detect custom theme for Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, themes, phpstorm

I am running PhpStorm on Debian 8 and am running into problems install a custom theme from https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes.

The problem comes when I download the theme as a icls file  to

```
~/.PhpStorm2016.3/config/colors
```

I restart the IDE and it doesn't detect the new theme. I have set the permissions to match the existing theme file already in the directory.

This is the file list

```
- -rw-r--r-- 1 munderwood munderwood 441913 Jan 29 12:10 legacy.icls
- -rw-r--r-- 1 munderwood munderwood    602 Jan 22 20:22 _@user_Darcula.icls
```

Darcula is the theme that came with the editor. Legacy is the one I am trying to get to work. I used `wget` to install it.

Comment: Please provide screenshots that will show "does not detect" situation. It's possible 1) that you are confused with Editor color schema and GUI Theme; 2) Have you tried restarting IDE? AFAIK such stuff gets loaded on startup only.

Comment: Where will it say "does not detect"?

Comment: aha i have found the error in the idea.log. The stack trace is quite big though so it would be a pain to paste. It says "Cannot read scheme legacy.icls 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: name is missed in the scheme data"

Comment: Ahh man.  Yeah I know what went wrong. When doing a wget I got the website and not the actual contents of the file. Embarrasing, im marking as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a wget on the https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes/blob/master/jetbrains/legacy.icls I was obv getting the page and not the contents in the file. Total fail.